# angular 4 app deployed on tomcat not rerouting properly after okta authentication

Tags: angular, tomcat, navigation, httpserver

I have deployed my angular 4 app in tomcat server, but after authenticating with okta, it is not redirecting other page even though I am using `navigateByUrl()`.

But the same works on node js when running ng serve command.

```
showProductsPage(){ 
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/products');}  
   showLogin() {
      this.oktaSignIn.renderEl({el: '#okta-login-container'}, (response) 
      if (response.status === 'SUCCESS') {
        this.user = response.claims.email;
        this.oktaSignIn.session.get((sessionResponse) => {
            this.userId = sessionResponse.login.indexOf('@') > -1 ? sessionResponse.login.split("@")[0] : sessionResponse.login;
            localStorage.setItem('tkid',this.userId);
            this.showProductsPage();
            //this.router.navigate(['products']);
        }); 
    }
```

I Tried with HashLocationStrategy but not sure how it can help me in this scenario

Comment: When used HashLocationStrategy I am getting Url hostname/#/products but the page was not being displayed

Comment: any error in console ?

Comment: I had a similar problem with IIS server and an ASP.net Core app, Hash LocationStrategy solved the problem but created others, at the end I returned to PathLocationStrategy and configuring the correct way the backend (routes) to avoid override routes that belong to angular. If ng serve works I think your problem is on the server.

Comment: You should review how your server handle the routes because angular apps should work well standalone or side by side with your backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented

import {HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
-useHash:true in the imports
-{provide: LocationStrategy,useClass:HashLocationStrategy}

Basically this is an error on okta side, but using HashLocationStrategy I solved this

Comment: Hi there, you implemented this on you angular application side? or you modified the @okta/okta-angular if you were using this.